# How to use SwaggerResponse after uprading Swashbuckle in net5 web api?

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle, asp.net5

We have a Web API with ~150 controllers (~500 methods) which we upgraded from Core2.2 to net5.0 and along with it we upgraded the Swashbuckle package.

The old version of Swashbuckle used `SwaggerResponse` attribute to display information on SwaggerUI and we used it heavily over our ~500 methods.

At some point the `SwaggerResponse` attribute was deprecated and the recommended solution is a different approach:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/159

Is there a way to

- either use the `SwaggerResponse` attribute in latest Swashbuckle, or
- convert the existing code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's recommended that you use [`ProduceResponseTypeAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.producesresponsetypeattribute?view=aspnetcore-5.0), However you can still use `SwaggerResponse` via the NuGet package [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations/).

The type `SwaggerResponse` wasn't completely removed it was just moved away from the main Swashbuckle package namely **Swashbuckle.AspNetCore** to an optional extra package **Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations**

Comment: Ha! All I had to do is ready docs properly ‍♂️ https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#swashbuckleaspnetcoreannotations as I forgot to `c.EnableAnnotations();`